# "if" clause within s-format string

Tags: string, helm-bibtex

Is it possible to add an "if" clause to a `s-format` string? The code below is adapted from `bibtex-completion-apa-format-reference` in the `helm-bibtex` package.

```elisp
(s-format
               "${author} (${date}). ${title}. In ${editor} (Eds.), ${booktitle} (pp. ${pages}). ${address}: ${publisher}."
               'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value entry)
```

I would like to add the biblatex field `${origdate}` like so if it exists.

```elisp
(s-format
               "${author} (${date}[${origdate}]). ${title}. In ${editor} (Eds.), ${booktitle} (pp. ${pages}). ${address}: ${publisher}."
               'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value entry)
```

The above code produces this when `origdate` is empty:

> author (2020[]). Title. In ...

I would like `s-format` to use `(${date})` when `origdate` is empty and `(${date}[${origdate}])` when `origdate` is present.

I can certainly nest the two sets of `s-format` code above under an `if` function to produce the desired results:

```elisp
(if (origdate-is-empty)
    (s-format
     "${author} (${date}). ${title}. In ${editor} (Eds.), ${booktitle} (pp. ${pages}). ${address}: ${publisher}."
     'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value entry)
  (s-format
   "${author} (${date}[${origdate}]). ${title}. In ${editor} (Eds.), ${booktitle} (pp. ${pages}). ${address}: ${publisher}."
   'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value entry))
```

Just like to know whether there is a more concise way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a constant string you can use an expression that returns your template. Assuming `origdate-is-empty` is a valid function that returns `nil` if `origdate` is not empty you can use something like this

```
(s-format
 (concat "${author} (${date}"
         (unless (origdate-is-empty) "[${origdate}]")
         "). ${title}. In ${editor} (Eds.), ${booktitle} (pp. ${pages}). ${address}: ${publisher}.")
 'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value entry)
```